# Accessing external HDD on different Windows computers with the same path

Tags: windows, hard-drive, icons, path, environment-variables

I have a external HDD and have a folder in it called `icons\` which stores all the custom icons (yes, I'm nostalgic!) for the different folders on my drive. But when I open my hard-drive on a different system (dealing only w/ Windows here), it doesn't show the icons I chose. I guess this is b'coz the paths change. How do I fix this?

**[Edit:]** After thinking this through, I'm guessing the reason this might not be possible is that every-where, the hard-drive won't get assigned the same letter. For example: On my desktop, it might be `F:\` and on my laptop it might be `G:\`. And the letter would also change if you connected the HDD to a different USB port. How can I fix this? Use some system variable to know which drive the HDD is connected to?

**[Edit:]** Somebody suggested using *relative paths* -- e.g., `icons\my_icon.ico` -- but that didn't work :(

**[Edit:]** I found the [environment variables](http://goo.gl/1QJ0k) that I was talking about. What if I used `%cd%` for the path of the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths (eg `\icons\my_icon.ico`)